# Sorting Excel Entries Into Separate Sheets By Date

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that has a Service Date in Column E. I've been trying to separate all rows with dates that aren't the first of a month into a separate worksheet and leave all rows with dates that do fall on the first of a month.

I've been able to find some solutions to similar problems, but I don't know VBA very well so adapting the solutions I've found has so far been an insurmountable task.

It's a fairly simple task, but doing it manually has gotten to be way too time consuming with recent growth in what this sheet tracks. A way to automate separating things that are done on the first of the month from things that aren't would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Please post some of the solutions you've found so far and explain what you've tried to adapt them, even if you haven't gotten very far.

Comment: Generally speaking you should have at least some level of VBA knowledge before you look for VBA solutions. It is unwise to pull code you can't read from the internet and incorporate it into your workplace files, for 2 main reasons: (1) the code could be malicious; and (2) it will prevent you from learning the skill yourself, and could therefore leave you 'stranded' at your job if the specifics of the situation change and you are no longer able to operate your macros.

Comment: I tried adapting some of the code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914163/separating-data-and-placing-in-individual-worksheets-excel-vba but getting it right was beyond my ken. I'm having a lot of problems getting both things I've tried adapting to actually recognize the dates I need to separate out, whether I list them individually (01/01/YYYY, 02/01/YYYY, etc) or try to express "first of the month" using code.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have tried, and specifically state the problems you are having trying to edit it for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very fast even with a manual procedcure, e.g.

1. create a temporary column heading "DayOfMonth"
2. fill this column with formula `=DAY([servicedate])`
3. sort by temporary column ... all "first of month" are on top
4. cut/paste anything where day of month > 1 to another sheet

Answer (score 0):

If you column of dates starts in cell E1, you can enter this formula into cell F1 and all the cells below.

```
=IF(MONTH($E1-1)<>MONTH($E1),"1st Of Month","")
```

By subtracting 1 from a date you get the date of the the previous day.  The IF statement therefore compares the month of the previous day with the month of today.

You could use a similar technique in VBA, but I suspect you might not need to.

Once you have a value in the column you can use the "Autofilter" functionality to only show the 1st of the month rows.  highlight all the rows and paste into another sheet and only the visible rows will be pasted  in.

Ok?

Harvey

Comment: sorry yes - you are right ... I initially overlooked your `<>` and had only `<` in my mind ... which is a common mistake I corrected a dozen times already ... hence I removed the 2nd part of my comment again ;-)