# Keep row header formatting when separating data and placing into individual worksheets Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I found vba code on this site for the issue I was having to break down a large data sheet into separate individual sheets based on a unique identifier (Organization).  In the source list, the row headers are formatted with bold lettering and a gray background, but when I run the macro, the new sheets lack any formatting. What I would like to add to my VBA code is to keep the row header formatting the same across all the new sheets, instead of the plain text with no formatting.  Due to the nature of the information, I cannot share an example of the macro output.

The link below will show my formatted row headers:

[Row Headers with Formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R80Jb.jpg)

Here is my vba code:

```
Sub FilterToSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Active & Inactive Accounts")
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' stop processing if we don't have any data
If LastRow < 2 Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
SortMasterList LastRow, ws
CopyDataToSheets LastRow, ws
ws.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub SortMasterList(LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet)
ws.Range("A2:H" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=ws.Range("A1"), Key2:=ws.Range("B1")
End Sub

Sub CopyDataToSheets(LastRow As Long, src As Worksheet)
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim Series As String
Dim SeriesStart As Long
Dim SeriesLast As Long

Set rng = Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
SeriesStart = 2
Series = Range("A" & SeriesStart).Value
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value <> Series Then
        SeriesLast = cell.Row - 1
        CopySeriesToNewSheet src, SeriesStart, SeriesLast, Series
        Series = cell.Value
        SeriesStart = cell.Row
    End If
Next
' copy the last series
SeriesLast = LastRow
CopySeriesToNewSheet src, SeriesStart, SeriesLast, Series

End Sub

Sub CopySeriesToNewSheet(src As Worksheet, Start As Long, Last As Long, _
                                                    name As String)

name = Left(name, 31)
Dim tgt As Worksheet

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).name = name
Set tgt = Sheets(name)

' copy header row from src to tgt
tgt.Range("A1:H1").Value = src.Range("A1:H1").Value

' copy data from src to tgt
tgt.Range("A2:H" & Last - Start + 2).Value = _
    src.Range("A" & Start & ":H" & Last).Value
End Sub

Function SheetExists(name As String) As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet

SheetExists = True
On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Sheets(name)
If ws Is Nothing Then
   SheetExists = False
End If
End Function
```

If it is also possible, I would like to keep the cell spacing the same across all the sheets, as the macro condenses the data in the new sheets.

[Where I found my vba code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914163/separating-data-and-placing-in-individual-worksheets-excel-vba)

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro whilst adding the desired formatting to one of your new sheets? You could use this as  a separate routine you could call to apply formatting to each of your new sheets?

Comment: I have not tried that, but how would I make it loop through all the sheets?  It generates over 100 new sheets when I run the macro

Comment: If CopySeriesToNewSheet creates each new sheet you would call the formatting sub after this line Set tgt = Sheets(name) and use the variable tgt as an argument to your formatting sub so it applied to the newly created sheet. This assumes same number of columns in header row for each sheet.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed my problem, I should have known it was this easy